# Run Cassandra query using Solr without using Datstax

Tags: solr, cassandra, cql

I currently set up a Solr indexing schema with one of my databases in Cassandra. I am able to run queries using the Solr Admin UI when visiting my local IP address with the appropriate port. However, I am unable to run any queries when trying CQL Solr Queries. Running a line such as `SELECT * FROM keyspace.table WHERE solr_query='name: cat name: dog -name:fish'` results in a "unknown column solr_query" error. I also tried adding the line `<requestHandler class="com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.handler.component.CqlSearchHandler" name="solr_query" />` to my solrconfig.xml as was mentioned in https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchCql.html but got a "Could not load class" error. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the jar file to Solr? See https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchConfLibPath.html

Comment: So I didn't use Datastax at all when setting up Solr. Followed this guideline: https://snapdev.net/2017/08/03/install-solr-on-ubuntu-14-04-or-16-06-without-datastax-dse/

Wasn't sure where to appropriately place the Jar file for that reason.

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need DSE for solr_query to work, since it extends Cassandra with a Solr connector.

Comment: Ah that makes sense